# AngularJS creating dummy directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create in AngularJS a "dummy" element to make nested ng-repeats.
So that following

```
data.test = [{h:1, d:[11,12]}, {h:2, d:[21,22]}];
----------------------
<dummy ng-repeat="a in data.test">
    <h3>{{a.h}}</h3>
    <p ng-repeat="b in a.d">{{b}}</p>
</dummy>
```

will expand into

```
<h3>1</h3>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<h3>2</h3>
<p>21</p>
<p>22</p>
```

Note that I don't want to be each group in `div` or any other element.

I have tried following directive

```
app.directive('dummy', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: ''
    };
});
```

However, it seems like it is preserving `dummy` nodes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directives [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) can be used for this exact purpose.

```
<h3 ng-repeat-start="a in data.test">{{a.h}}</h3>
<p ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="b in a.d">{{b}}</p>
```

without need for a dummy element/directive, as can be seen [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8UsRsOQmRFkzSoYhfmaf?p=preview).

Comment: But there is no collection-repeat-start/end

Answer (score 0):

After searching Google, I found a blog post that answer this. It shows how to [group with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/displaying-groups-with-angularjs-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-with-example). There's a running example with downloadable code. If you jump to the end, you can see the code that looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="TeamListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat-start="team in teams" class="header">{{team.name}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="player in team.players" class="item">{{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat-end><br /></div>
</body>
```